# SSHD PORT 22 , W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied . working on a PORT 8888 WHY?

Tags: java, android, ssh, ssh-tunnel

i want to connect two mobile remotely using SSHD  i found below code on stack i installed all the lib and dependencies and internet permission . code is working server is running on PORT 8888

```
public void startSSHServer() {
int port = 8888;
SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshd.setPort(port);
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(
        "src/test/resources/hostkey.ser"));
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Arrays
        .<NamedFactory<Command>> asList(new SftpSubsystem.Factory()));
sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());
sshd.setShellFactory(new ProcessShellFactory(new String[] { "/system/bin/sh", "-i", "-l" })); // necessary if you want to type commands over ssh
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String u, String p, ServerSession s) {
        return ("sftptest".equals(u) && "sftptest".equals(p));
    }
});

try {
    sshd.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

as far as I know SSH uses PORT 22 so i change the PORT 22 the i got this SYSTEM ERROR

```
    W/System.err: SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11]
W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
W/System.err: 89 [Thread-3] INFO org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle already registered as a JCE provider
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:442)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:434)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:248)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:48)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.registerHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:525)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.access$200(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:66)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:406)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` on AndroidMenifest.xml ?
If not adding that should fix the issue

Comment: yes     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Did you try running the same code on a different android device ? this probably happening because some other app is using port 22

Comment: i scan my opened port using port droid  app no port is on now i will run this on other phone and make sure

Comment: @ Shubho Brata Roy   i tried on other device same result any idea  . i want to transfer file using sshd server and a jsch is it required to root the phone to work on port 22